# Why does my repo have so many Context Providers? And is this normal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, devtools

When I open up my Dev Tools for the React Native Project I am working on, everything seems to be wrapped dozens of times in a Context Provider. I am not even using the Context API in my project. I have included An ActionSheet Provider & a Paper Provider, but that is it. I am just wondering if anyone has made this mistake and if I should instead be setting up the root of my component tree a bit differently. [image: ContextProviders]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening often in libraries such as Paper, because the Provider HOC passing down props to all child Paper components

Comment: So is this normal? Should I change something? Or is this okay?

Comment: Nothing you can do if you are using such workaround